# hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto value to do both the operations i.e create/update on database schema?

Tags: java, hibernate

i  want to know for now, Is it possible in hibernate to create database schema if schema does not exist otherwise update the schema
if it is already exist and there are some modification in hbm file with some value for property hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto .

As per my understanding 
**create value** will always drop the previous schema and  create the new schema ? 
**update value**  will not create new schema, it will just update the schem if exist a based on hbm.xml. **Right?**

**Mine scheme is local schema not a production schema.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `update` value for `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` will indeed create new schema if it does not exist.

Comment: Hi Dev,so you sre saying update does both, it creates the schema if it does not exist and updates the schema if there is any modification. But i do not see any such statement at http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html. Could you tell me where in hibernate doc i can confirm it? As answer by Murali above,looks like update does not create the schema.Wanted to confirm it.Thanks for Reply.

Comment: It isn't in the documentation at least that I could find. I have been using that setting in development work though. It has limitations. It will not change already mapped data or remove it. It will however add columns, tables, etc to an existing schema that don't exist already if they need to be. You should create a test project, which a few simple pojos and map them then change the mapping between deployments (i.e. adding fields), it would not be hard to rig up.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use SchemaExport, you can just use SchemaUpdate. It works great and you can review the sql before you choose to commit if you like.

You do need to create the database yourself, or use some jdbc for that. And then:

```
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate;

public static void updateDb(Configuration cfg, boolean printSqlToConsole, boolean commit)
{
    SchemaUpdate u = new SchemaUpdate(cfg);
    u.setFormat(printSqlToConsole);
    u.execute(printSqlToConsole, commit);
}
```

**Note:** that it cannot handle renamed/changed fields, you need to take care of that. But it can handle new fields. Fields that are not mapped are ignored.